# Chain Two request and return an object Angular 7

Tags: angular-http, angular2-observables, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient-interceptors

I have a request to search the notifications that match with an user input search, but each notifications that match have a newsId properties, I want when I got the notification from server, make another request to search the news obj from the newsId properties and after return an obj with the notification obj and news obj

```
import { Notification } from './notification';
import { New } from './new';

export class NotificationEditResponse {
  notification:Notification;
  newsBelong?:New;
  error?:any;
}



export class EditNotificationsResolverService implements Resolve <NotificationEditResponse> {

  constructor(private notificationService:NotificationsService) { }

  return this.notificationService.getNotificationById(+id)
.pipe(
  flatMap(notificationObj=>{
    return this.newsService.getNewById(notificationObj.newsId)
    .pipe(
      map((res:New)=>({
        notification:notificationObj,
        newsBelong:res
      })),
    catchError(error=>{
    const msg=`Retrieval error : ${error}`;
    console.log(msg);
    return of({notification:null, error:msg,newsBelong:null});
  })
    )
  })
 );
```

}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap` because according to your use case `this.newsService.getNewById` should wait for `this.notificationService.getNotificationById` to emit a value.